# How to Output "custom taxonomy description" to a post body or a widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, archive

I have a custom taxonomy : 'actor'.

I can click, edit and read that "actor description" at the archive correctly.
Till here ok.

But now i need to output that custom taxonomy description archive on each corresponding post body, or lets say in a widget.

i did try testing with the following codes:

```
term_description($term_id, 'actor'); 


echo category_description( get_category_by_slug('actor')->term_id );

global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo category_description( get_category_by_slug('actor')->term_id );
wp_reset_query();
```

Or something related to "$loop_desc = " 
i dont know, i think im missing something...  And i know shouldn't be that hard.
Any suggestions?? Thanks! :)